# JUnit not null test

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to implement an easy junit test for a method. My intention is to test if the method parameter is not `null`. So that the test fails if the parameter is `null`.

the method is:

```
/*
 * @return the db entry object
*/
getEntry( String user, String grp, int status);
```

My first try to implement the test is

```
public void testGetEntry() {
    String userId = null;
    getEntry( userId, "grp1", 3);
    asserNotNull(userId);
}
```

I think thats not the correct way. thx for any help :)

Comment: Surely you need your *test* to validate that the method behaves correctly if the parameter *is* null - for example, checking that an exception is thrown. So, what *do* you want the method to do when the parameter is null? The check for that can't be in the test - it has to be in the production method.

Comment: In your example, `userId` will *always* be null on the assert line, regardless of what `getEntry` does.

Comment: I do not know if you really understand yourself what you try to accomplish, definetly we can not. Try to rethink what you try to do and explain it clearly

Answer (score 3):

You can't test that. 
You can test a beavhior like : "Check that a IllegalArgumentException is thrown if a null parameter is passed". A unit test for testing if a parameter is not null does not make sense, it is not the purpose of unit testing : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing

Here, "test if the method parameter is not null" should be done in the method.

Comment: Ok. i have to catch a possible NullPointerEx with the test. Am I right?

Comment: Do not play with fire, what will you do if you catch a NullPointerException ?If you don't want a null parameter for your method then check them first and throw yourself a IllegalArgumentException.

Answer (score 3):

You should definitely check out [NullPointerTester](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r143/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/testing/NullPointerTester.html) from [Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/). You use it in your tests like this:

```
new NullPointerTester().testAllPublicInstanceMethods(YourClass.class)
```

Then you need to annotate your methods with [JSR-305](https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/)s [@NonNull](https://code.google.com/p/jsr-305/source/browse/trunk/ri/src/main/java/javax/annotation/Nonnull.java)

```
getEntry(@NonNull String user, @NonNull String grp, int status);
```

Then use [Preconditions](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html) checkNotNull in your production code.

```
getEntry(@NonNull String user, @NonNull String grp, int status)
{
     Preconditions.checkNotNull(user, "user must be specified");
     Preconditions.checkNotNull(grp, "grp must be specified");
     //return entry;
}
```

This will make other classes receive a NullPointerException when they misuse your class. When they receive this they'll know that they did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In order to check that your method doesn't have a null parameter, you need to use Mockito and mock the class( let's call it C.java) where this  method ( let's call it m(param) )  is declared. Of course class C should NOT be the class you want to test (a mock is a "dummy" implementation).

If you are in the case where you are calling the method m of class C and you want to verify that the argument "param" of m(param) is not null, here is how to do it :

```
C cMock= Mockito.mock(C.class);
verify(cMock).m(isNotNull());
```

Here is some useful documentation :

http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.6/javadoc/org/mockito/Matchers.html

http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/branches/1.5/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html

I hope this helps

Regards